# Unit testing in the browser

Tags: unit-testing, firefox-addon-sdk, commonjs

I prefer unit testing in the browser because I enjoy [the legible formatting](http://timgilbert.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/mocha-pending-specs.png) of testing frameworks like mocha.

Is there an easy way run add-on sdk unit tests in the browser?

Edit: I'm not looking to do regression testing. With mocha, for example, I can create an HTML page like this:

```
<head>
  <title>Tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mocha.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <script src="mocha.js"></script>
  <script src="chai.js"></script>
  <script src="main-content.js"></script>
  <script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>
  <script src="main-content-test.js"></script>
  <script>
    mocha.run();
  </script>
</body>
```

The output looks like the picture I linked to above. This is what I mean by unit testing in the browser.

Edit 2: I'm trying to unit test my modules (using require("sdk/test"), not my content scripts.

Comment: Almost by definition, browser testing is not unit testing. You may be referring to regression testing, where you collect a set of tests and can run them automatically in a framework. Are you aware of Selenium?

Comment: @BobDalgleish front-end Javascript is routinely unit-tested in the browser. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a prebuilt way to do this, it would require a little jerry-rigging.

All that you need in addition to your page is a page-mod like this:

```
require('sdk/page-mod').PageMod({
  include: require('sdk/self').data.url('testpage.html'),
  contentScript: 'unsafeWindow.addon={on: self.port.on, emit: self.port.emit}',
  contentScriptWhen: 'start',
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.on('test-1', function() {
      worker.port.emit('test-1', {})
    });
    // ...
  }
});
```

which would listen for test events, perform the test, and emit the results back.  Then your test page test code would listen for the test results like so:

```
function test() {
  addon.on('test-1', function(results) {
    //  loop through results and pass/fail
  });
  addon.emit('test-1');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I understand the above correctly, it's for testing content scripts. However, I'm trying to unit test my modules (using `require("sdk/test")`) in a way that is similar in appearance to the mocha framework. I included the HTML page simply to show that unit testing is possible in the browser. Please let me know if I've misunderstood.